# How to Read Json File Without Giving Element Names in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I want to read json file as follow;

```
{
  "M": {
  "row": [
  {
  "col1": "c00"
  },
  {
  "col1": "c10",
  "col2": "c11"
  },
  {
  "col1": "c20",
  "col2": "c21",
  "col3": "c22"
  }
  ]
  }
}
```

Next to reading, I want to print "c00","c10","c11","c20","c21","c22" but without giving element as "col1","col2","col3"...
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Typically JSON libraries such as GSON or Jackson will de-serialize to a `Map` for you without the need for a given POJO with all the properties.

Comment: Question is not clear. Nothing is defined about JSON string keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any JSON parsing library such as [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and convert it into Java Object.

Sample code using GSON library

```
 Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
 Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
 System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
 // get the desired value from map

 Map<String,ArrayList<Map<String,String>>> mMap=(Map<String,ArrayList<Map<String,String>>>)data.get("M");
 ArrayList<Map<String,String>> rowArray=mMap.get("row");
 for(Map<String,String> colMap:rowArray){
     for(String value:colMap.values()){
         System.out.println(value);
     }
 }
```

---

You can convert JSON string into Java POJO class as well that is replica of the JSON string

```
class MDetails {
    private MDetail M;
    // getter & setter
}

class MDetail {
    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> row;
    // getter & setter
}

...
MDetails data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MDetails.class);
for (Map<String, String> colMap : data.getM().getRow()) {
    for (String value : colMap.values()) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

---

You can use different field name using `@SerializedName` annotation.

```
 class MDetails {
    @SerializedName("M")
    private MDetail mDetail;
    // getter & setter         
 }
```

---

As per comments, the keys are dynamic so iterate the map containing another map in it and print all the values whose key starts with `col`

sample code: (call below method that **recursively** iterate all keys and values)

```
public static void printColValues(Object data) {
    if (data instanceof Map) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : ((Map<String, Object>) data).entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            if (key.startsWith("col")) {
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            } else {
                printColValues(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    } else if (data instanceof List) {
        for (Object obj : (List) data) {
            printColValues(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
c00
c10
c11
c20
c21
c22
```

---

OR if nothing works then try with regex pattern but keep it as last resort

```
("col\d+":)("[^"]*")
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/zF6lC9/6)

Or try with Reluctant Qualifier

```
("col\d+":)(".*?")
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/zF6lC9/5)

sample code:

```
String jsonString = "{\"M\":{\"row\":[{\"col1\":\"c00\"},{\"col1\":\"c10\",\"col2\":\"c11\"},{\"col1\":\"c20\",\"col2\":\"c21\",\"col3\":\"c22\"}]}}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"col\\d+\":)(\"[^\"]*\")");
Matcher m = p.matcher(jsonString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

output:

```
"c00"
"c10"
"c11"
"c20"
"c21"
"c22"
```

---

Code updated to print all values regardless of keys

```
public static void printColValues(Object data) {
    if (data instanceof Map) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : ((Map<String, Object>) data).entrySet()) {
            Object value=entry.getValue();
            if (value instanceof String) {
                System.out.println(value);
            } else {
                printColValues(value);
            }
        }
    } else if (data instanceof List) {
        for (Object obj : (List) data) {
            printColValues(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very good, running code thanks. Well is it posible getting method that without root element "M" and node element "row"?

Comment: yes Iterate all the values of the `Map` and inspect the keys if key starts with `col` then print its value.

Comment: As I told you iterate all the Map inside another Map and just check for keys if it starts with `col` then print the value. Do you know how to iterate the Map having another Map inside it?

Comment: code updated just pass the `Map<String,Object> data` in the above mentioned method.

Comment: Is there any thing that is static? So you are interested on all values?

Comment: I write this code:
`for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
     String rootElement = entry.getKey();
     System.out.println(rootElement);
}`

Output: `M`

I locate in this code:
`Map<String,ArrayList<Map<String,String>>>mMap=(Map<String,ArrayList<Map<String,‌​String>>>)data.get(rootElement);`

I need a code output that it is `row` string.
`ArrayList<Map<String,String>> rowArray=mMap.get("row");`

Comment: I have shared the code and it prints what is expected? Why you are not trying my code?

Comment: Thanks for all the regex is running but I don't must to use regex.

Comment: Look at last example that prints all `String` values and this is my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.json` library for this. It is [here](http://json.org/java/). General idea:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(sourceString);
for(String key : obj.keys()){
    String value = obj.getString(key);
    // Process value here
}
```

Comment: `obj` is not a `Map` instance. According to docs it doesn't have `keySet()` method.

Comment: keySet here. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java